# Why am I getting two outputs in place of a single one?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm writing a simple program and I am getting 2 outputs of the same data with a single `cout` statement.  I think something went wrong with my loop, but I am not able to find where the problem is.  If possible, please show me what I need to change; otherwise, I'd at least like to know why my logic is wrong.

#### My code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n ;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> arr(n);
    vector<int> a(n);
    for(int arr_i = 0;arr_i < n;arr_i++){
       cin >> arr[arr_i];
       a[arr_i]=1;
    }
    int i,least,flag,count=n;
    do{
        cout<<count<<endl;
        count=0;
        flag=1;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++){   //for getting least number
            if(a[i]){
                if(flag){
                    least=arr[i];
                    flag=0;    
                }
                if(arr[i]<least){
                    least=arr[i];
                }
            }
        }

        for(i=0;i<n;i++){       // for actual logic
            if(arr[i]<=0||!a[i]){
                a[i]=0;

                //continue;
            }
            else{    
            arr[i]-=least;
            count++;
            }
        }

    }while(count);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample input:

```
6
5 4 4 2 2 8
```

#### Expected output

```
6
4
2
1
```

#### Actual output:

```
6
6
4
4
2
2
1
1
```

#### Problem statement

You are given `N` sticks, where the length of each stick is a positive integer. A cut operation is performed on the sticks such that all of them are reduced by the length of the smallest stick.

Suppose we have six sticks of the following lengths:

```
5 4 4 2 2 8
```

Then, in one cut operation we make a cut of length 2 from each of the six sticks. For the next cut operation four sticks are left (of non-zero length), whose lengths are the following:

```
3 2 2 6
```

The above step is repeated until no sticks are left.

Given the length of `N` sticks, print the number of sticks that are left before each subsequent cut operations.

**Note:** For each cut operation, you have to recalculate the length of the smallest sticks (excluding zero-length sticks).

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85669/cutting-the-sticks

Comment: Best way to get a grip what's going on is to step through your code using the debugger, rather than asking at Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you are daunted by the prospect of learning to use a debugger, you can put some diagnostic `cout` statements in your code, such as `cout << "least is " << least << endl;`. This is a vital coding technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One noticed error: when substracting `least` from `arr[i]` and `arr[i]` becoming <=0 `a[i]` still stays non-zero, and at next iteration you getting least number the same as at previous iteration.

Other problem: your `count` is `count` of previous turn. At first iteration it equals 6, because condition `if(arr[i]<=0||!a[i])` dont fulfill for any number from input.

After fixing this part:

```
// for actual logic
if (a[i]) {
    arr[i] -= least;

    if (arr[i] <= 0)
        a[i] = 0;
    else
        count++;
}
```

it looks working nice.